# How to place text on both sides of md-switch?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to create an md-switch with text on both sides.
I tried creating it like this:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
   <p style="float: left">CSV Upload</p>
   <md-switch ng-model="ctrl.csvUploadMode">Lat-Long Mode</md-switch>
</div>
```

[image: But I am getting left side text on top like this:]

How to fix the left side text so that it aligns perfectly in the middle?

Comment: I think you should make `<p>` element inline by adding to style `display: inline;` and i would prefer to use another `<p>` element for right hand side text instead of using md-switch label like 
`<div class="col-md-2">
   <p ...>CSV Upload</p>
   <md-switch ng-model="ctrl.csvUploadMode"/>
   <p ...>Lat-Long Mode</p>
</div>`

Answer (score 1):

to make the title exactly at the centre with float: left, title should be exactly of the same height as right side, md-switch, so u need to add:
**(styles taken from md-switch)**

```
margin: 15px 0;
line-height: 28px;
float: left;
```

Check this https://codepen.io/surya-iitg/pen/LYVxMPp

Comment: the left text will be so close to switch. will try changing right-margin.